# Moving DOM elements below a fixed navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed navigation bar, however, any time I try to create content after it, the content clips the navigation.

I could fix this by using relative positioning on the content, but I would really prefer NOT to do that.

How can I push content below a fixed navigation bar without resorting to strange CSS tactics?

Example Navigation:

```
nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Putting the content class may have been misleading, Essentially, I want DOM elements to flow after the nav bar without clipping it. For example, imagine the following HTML coming after the nav:

```
<section>foo</section>
<p>bar</p>
<h2>fubar</h2>
<div>blah blah blah </div>
```

I would like to see the section come after the nav bar, and then the p after the section and so forth.

Original Example Problem (Not Reflective of the problem):
http://jsfiddle.net/wZHcv/

New Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4MLVT/

Comment: Why do you consider it to be a strange tactic? You can always add padding-top. That's normally what you would do for example if you had headers with anchor links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put nav inside a div , then set the height of the div by nav height. The advantage of this: easier and more meaningful,and In other places you can use other code without concerns..

```
<div class="nav-box">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">bar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zsytssk/aSB42/)

Comment: +1 because this is a great suggestion, though it will behave oddly if the `body` has nonzero margins. (I'd suggest adding `body{margin:0;}` as well)

Comment: This is closest to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We should wrap the content after navigation in a div and set position:relative and top greater than the height of the navigation bar.

```
HTML CODE:
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">bar</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
   <section>foo</section>
   <p>bar</p>
   <h2>fubar</h2>
   <div>blah blah blah </div>
</div>

CSS CODE:
nav{
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline;
}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
font-size:20px;
-webkit-transition:all .5s;
padding:5px;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
background:black;
color:white;
}
.content{
position:relative;
top:60px;
}
```