# Why is my <div> disappearing behind another?

Tags: css, html

Long story short, I am creating a webpage that has a fixed wrapper `<div>` across the top and a small amount of "content" underneath it that you can scroll up and down from.

Problem is that my "content" `<div>` doesn't start from the bottom of the wrapper `<div>` but further up the page underneath it

Here's an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UquqK/)

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #327bb7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving DOM elements below a fixed navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754836/moving-dom-elements-below-a-fixed-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the:

```
position:fixed;
```

Add for example:

```
position: relative;
```

to `#content`.

or

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
```

the last if you want to append the content below the fixed area.

Comment: But I want my wrapper to be fixed, how do I get the content div to start lower than it? not pushed up the page

Answer (score 0):

add **padding-top : 100px Or whatever you want**

> but basically the padding will be the height of the wrapper.

```
#content {
    padding-top : 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements of your layout you might want to try something like this.

```
document.getElementById("content").style.marginTop = document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height;
```