# I cannot see the whole screen with Twitter bootstrap when having a fixed menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you see this JSFiddle demo, http://jsfiddle.net/4K5Sk/1/ you can see this screen:

[image]

Why doesn't it start with the line of "TEST 1"?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#menu1">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu2">menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu3">menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    TEST 1<br />
    TEST 2<br />
    TEST 3<br />
    TEST 4<br />
    TEST 5<br />        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Bootstrap 3 docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)...

> "Body padding required
>   The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high."

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the position of the navigation is fixed. This element doesn't contribute to the height of the page. Which means that it doesn't push the container down.

To fix this, just add a margin-top to your container in order to put it below the navigation (50px should be enough as this is the height of the navigation).

http://jsfiddle.net/4K5Sk/2/

```
.container-fluid{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: This is for sure not very responsive (to put in a fixed height). If I add more menu elements so it expands to multiple lines, it will not be true anymore. Can't I put in both the menu and the content in two containers or alike (I tried it but it didn't work)?

Comment: you could put a container around the navigation (cfr. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754836/moving-dom-elements-below-a-fixed-navigation-bar) but then again you'll have to give this wrapper a fixed height. Otherwise it will have height 0. So if you want it truely responsive you should consider a non-fixed navigation. Or you could use an image on top (with no important content), this way it wouldn't be bad if part of the image isn't seen.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted @Skelly's answer as this is the official documentation but I have tweaked it to be a little more dynamic so it will automatically find the position.

I have the exact code as my original post - excel that I add a class to the first line:

`<div class="mymenu navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">`

Javascript:

```
// Position the text after the menu when loading page initially
var menuheight = $(".mymenu").height();
$("body").css("padding-top",menuheight);

// Position the text after the menu when resizing the page
$(window).resize(function () {
  var menuheight = $(".mymenu").height();
  $("body").css("padding-top",menuheight);
});
```

Updated Fiffle here, http://jsfiddle.net/4K5Sk/3/